# Nginx seems to be redirecting to wrong proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

This is a project for a cryptography class where I'm learning about self signed certficates and I chose nginx to help me with my app.

I have a docker-compose.yml that hosts a python api, postgres, pgadmin and nginx. Most of my endpoints should be for the python api, but what if I want to access pgadmin remotely?

The problem is, I'm trying to access pgadmin but my request gets sent to the python api. I believe this, since the error is sent from the python api "Cannot find passed url".

When trying to access pgadmin remotely, I go with "http://ip-address/pgadmin"

Note that I can access pgadmin inside the local machine when using curl localhost:pgadmin-port.

I get returned pgadmin's html.

Here's the nginx.conf

```
events {
    worker_connections 1000;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/selfsigned/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/selfsigned/server.key;
        ssl_client_certificate  /etc/ssl/selfsigned/ca.crt;
        ssl_verify_client       optional;

        location /app {
            proxy_pass http://app:5000;
        }

        location ~ ^/api/ {
            if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS") {
                return 403;
                }
            proxy_pass http://app:5000$request_uri;
        }
        
        location /pgadmin {
            proxy_pass http://pgadmin:80;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        env_file:
            - ./database.env
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        container_name: postgres_database
  
    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        env_file:
            - ./pgadmin.env
        ports:
            - "80"
        depends_on:
            - db
        container_name: pgadmin4
  
    app:
        build:
            context: app
        ports:
            - "5000"
        depends_on:
            db:
                condition: service_started
        container_name: flask_app

    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
            - /etc/ssl/selfsigned:/etc/ssl/selfsigned
        depends_on:
            - app
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        container_name: nginx
```